# Transparent patterns in shading

Tags: texturing, shaders, transparency

Hey guys trying to bake a transparent texture via Shading to a 3d model - .obj with a UV map - I have - black stripes with transparent background .png - but it's causing some trouble.

It seems to add a non-transparent gray layer in place where it should remain transparent.

Worse part is I made it work one time - but I didn't save a screenshot for reference of the node setup and now I'm lost again :facepalm:

This has been the setup I used: (in my case the texture was an image texture, and sorry for the quality but don't have access to my computer atm) I had narrow down the colorramp to project the texture, and Im pretty sure I made work once when I moved the `Alpha` of `Principled BSDF` to `0.0` but now it seems to return a fully black output in `Shading`, could someone please assist what am I missing

[image]